# Draw chessboard with frame with pure html and css

Tags: html, css

I have already finished a chessboard with pure HTML and CSS. But as I'm not a designer, and I can't figure out how to do a simple thing. I'm trying to make a frame around the board. I'm using CSS border property to make a margin in `table.chessboard` element (code below). But that margin expands inside the board and decreases the squares on borders.

What can I do to solve this?

Code:

```css
table.chessboard {
  margin: 80px auto;
  background: #999;
  border: 25px solid #333;
}

td.chessboard {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
}

tr.chessboard:nth-child(odd) td.chessboard:nth-child(even),
tr.chessboard:nth-child(even) td.chessboard:nth-child(odd) {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<table class="chessboard">
  <tr class="chessboard">
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <!-- line above 8 times -->
  </tr>
  <tr class="chessboard">
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <!-- line above 8 times -->
  </tr>
  <tr class="chessboard">
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <!-- line above 8 times -->
  </tr>
  <tr class="chessboard">
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <!-- line above 8 times -->
  </tr>
  <tr class="chessboard">
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <!-- line above 8 times -->
  </tr>
  <tr class="chessboard">
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <!-- line above 8 times -->
  </tr>
  <tr class="chessboard">
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <!-- line above 8 times -->
  </tr>
  <tr class="chessboard">
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <!-- line above 8 times -->
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you just want an outline around the squares?

Comment: Yes @ HolyMoly, exactly.

Comment: looks like someone beat me to it but there are your answers below, it's just the `border` property

Answer (score 6):

I assume you want to make a border around all the cells.

```css
table.chessboard {
    margin: 80px auto;
    background: #999;
    border: 25px solid #333;
    border-collapse: collapse; /* */
}
td.chessboard {
    width: 70px; height: 70px;
    border: 2px solid #333; /* */
}
tr.chessboard:nth-child(odd) td.chessboard:nth-child(even),
tr.chessboard:nth-child(even) td.chessboard:nth-child(odd) {
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<table class="chessboard">
<tr class="chessboard">
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="chessboard">
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="chessboard">
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="chessboard">
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="chessboard">
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="chessboard">
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="chessboard">
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="chessboard">
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry, In fact the border is around the chessboard, and not around the cells. I'm editing.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, I think that in tables the borders are part of their width. So the bigger the border, the smaller the cells.

Answer (score 0):

in your css:

```
table.chessboard { 
   border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

adjust width as desired ;)

Comment: Thanks @HolyMoly, but as I want a larger border (with about 25px) the problem will persist. If you put 25px in `board` class the squares next the board borders get decreased.

Comment: i'm looking at it in my broswer (with the code you posted) and it does not appear the cells are shrinking. can you do a screenshot of what you are seeing? Unless there are some other elements and css going on in the page that you did not post, this seems to be rendering as expected

Comment: Yes, all the code is here. I've made a change. When I add `border-collapse: separate;` in `table.chessboard` class the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chessboard using HTML and CSS</title>
        <style>
            .cboard-box {
                border: 1px solid #000;
                width: 560px;
                height: 560px;
            }
            .cboard-row {
                display: flex;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
            }
            .cboard-cell {
                width: 70px;
                height: 70px;
            }
            .cboard-row:nth-child(odd) .cboard-cell:nth-child(odd) {
                background: #fff;
            }
            .cboard-row:nth-child(odd) .cboard-cell:nth-child(even) {
                background: #000;
            }
            .cboard-row:nth-child(even) .cboard-cell:nth-child(even) {
                background: #fff;
            }
            .cboard-row:nth-child(even) .cboard-cell:nth-child(odd) {
                background: #000;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="cboard-box">
            <div class="cboard-row">
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="cboard-row">
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="cboard-row">
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="cboard-row">
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="cboard-row">
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="cboard-row">
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="cboard-row">
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="cboard-row">
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
                <div class="cboard-cell"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```